# Difference between output of Matlab backslash (\) and numpy.linalg.solve

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am trying to port MATLAB code to python, in which I have to solve a system of linear equations. I have a square matrix A and a vector B. The output given using MATLAB's backslash operator is different from numpy.linalg.solve, which is the numpy equivalent for a square matrix.

I have tried to use pinv(A)*B in Matlab and compare that to np.linalg.pinv(A)*B in python. They both give results consistent with the previous method tried in each language, but are not equal to each other. I am wondering if this error has to do with the precision that MATLAB and Python use for storing integers.

In Matlab:

```
x = A\B
```

In Python

```
x = np.linalg.solve(A, B)
```

Input matrix:

```
            A = np.array([[1.4496, 1.6599, 0.7432, 1.1793, 0.9570],
                         [1.6599, 2.1355, 0.7412, 1.6223, 1.1561],
                         [0.7432, 0.7412, 0.5723, 0.6121, 0.5772],
                         [1.1793, 1.6223, 0.6121, 1.5197, 0.9168],
                         [0.9570, 1.1561, 0.5772, 0.9168, 1.1206]])
            B = np.array([0.6908, 0.9390, 0.5756, 0.8842, 0.7343])
```

Matlab output:

```
x =

   -5.4568   
    5.7049    
    4.6153    
   -2.5657   
   -0.7871
```

Python output:

```
x = 
[-4.24662995  
 3.54417096  
 3.29377257 
-1.15847853 
-0.12329431]
```

Edit: Here's the MATLAB code

```
    for i = 1:class_num1
        A = (XX+r1*diag(D1(:,class_num1+i))+r2*D2);
        B = XY1(:,i);
        P(:,i) = A\B;
    end;
```

Comment: Please provide the input matrix and vector so that others can reproduce your example.

Comment: Are you sure you didn’t accidentally transpose the matrix when translating the code?

Comment: The Matlab result that you show is not a solution to Ax=B for the A and B that you show.

Comment: Show the complete [Matlab code that produces that result](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: There must be something wrong in your MATLAB code. Using the numbers you provided, MATLABs `A \ B` gives the same results as numpys `linalg.solve(A,B)`, i.e. the second result you posted (the one starting with x[0] = -4.2466...). Just verified with MATLAB 2017a and Numpy 1.16.4

Comment: Please make MATLAB code that inputs the matrix directly, rather than cryptic code that uses data we don't have. Make the MATLAB code reproducible, in the same way that the Python code is. That way we can copy-paste and see what you're seeing.